# how to seperate integer values from a string and store it into a variable in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get battery voltage using a micro controller which is returning value like this:

> 1,1.93

So I have to separate this `1,1.93` value from this string and store it into a variable. I have used "REGEX" and "SPLIT" but both are returning

> 1
>   1
>   93

how could i get it like 1,1.93

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.27.123/Command=dvsync");
    WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
    StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
    String val4 = (rd.ReadToEnd());
    textBox3.Text = val4;
    MessageBox.Show("Value" + val4);

}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: If it's always like that then just using substring would easily work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it is between the opening and closing `<html>` tags  you can use the `Split` method the following way:

```
string test = "<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>1,1.93</html>";

string [] res = test.Split(new string[] {"<html>", "</html>"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

string number = res[1];
```

Comment: @MohammadHossain glad to hear. Out of curiousity: why do you need this crooked value? are these 2 numbers? how do you convert?

Comment: I am working for my university project. In this project i have to develop a controller which will send some data to a server using this application. i have already developed my GSM system based controller. But facing problem on designing this application. But u helped a lot.
And i do not need to convert to a single data. i will just through it to the server. server can cover it.

Answer (score 1):

Converting your input to double values requires parsing or your recevied data which can be done using the XElement. Then split and convert the values using the InvariantCulture.

```
string received = "<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>1,1.93</html>";
string parsedValue = XElement.Parse(received).Value;
double[] values = Array.ConvertAll(parsedValue.Split(','), v => double.Parse(v, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```